# Привести URL в одну форму

Tags: java, android, веб-программирование, url

Программирую на андроид. Почему-то подключение идёт лишь тогда, когда ссылка в формате http://google.com  и никак иначе.

```
url = new URL(serverURL); // на вход строка (тип String)
```

Как-то не хочется просить пользователя привести ссылку в строго в одну форму.

Comment: Почему бы не проверять начинается ли введённое юзером на `http://` и если нет до не добавлять программно?

Comment: Предлагаете рассмотреть все варианты? (Когда введёт или не введёт определённый участок ссылки?

Comment: Либо так, либо нейронную сеть пилить и обучать оную на сотнях юезров, страдающих дислексией и генерящих невалидные адреса. Как вы понимаете второй вариант трудозатратен и избыточен и проще ограничиться парой вариантов проверки и показом юзеру сообщения об ошибке и указанием как должен выглядеть валидный для вашей программы адрес.

Comment: в URL есть обязательные части. при отсутствии какой-либо из них, URL считается не правильным. и либо вы сами анализируете URL и исправляете, либо просите пользователя ввести правильный.